# Is it possible to find out which instance of a certain class called a certain class method last when that class method is called by another instance?

Tags: python

Sorry for the long title. No idea how to ask it more concisely.

To avoid repeating the title, here is an example:

```py
from random import choice

class Foo:
    def mymethod(self):
        # some code
        return
    def previous(self):
       ...

a = Foo()
b = Foo()
c = Foo()
d = Foo()
# etc ... 

for _ in range(10):
    x = choice([a, b, c, d])
    x.mymethod()
    x.previous()
```

What I am trying to achieve is make a class method `previous()` that prints/returns which instance of *Foo()* (a, b, c, d) called `mymethod()` right before the current instance called `mymethod()`

---

The WHY?

I have a script that makes HTTP requests to random endpoints of a certain host. These endpoints are different instances of the same class that uses a `request()` method to make the HTTP request.

There is a pandas DataFrame for each instance of this class (each endpoint) that holds data for each request such as response times. Along with this, I need the previous request that was made before the current request, hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class variable which is updated whenever an instance calls `mymethod` - note that the class variable itself is updated, not a variable bound to any particular instance.

```
class Foo:
    previous = None 

    def mymethod(self): 
        # do something 
        self.__class__.previous = self

a = Foo()
b = Foo()

a.mymethod()
a.previous == a  # True
b.previous == a  # True
a.previous == b  # False

b.mymethod()
a.previous == a  # False
b.previous == b  # True
```

Comment: What do you mean with "which instance holds the True value"?

Comment: @Heike the comments indicate to what boolean value each expression evaluates to. The instances themselves do not hold a True or False value in this case, but they do hold a "shared pointer" to whoever called `mymethod` last in their `previous` attribute.

Comment: @jfaccioni I understand how class attributes work. My question was actually in response to a comment that OP made but seems to have deleted now.